# Why do we use regularization for training neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

In my understanding, I think it's to avoid over/under fitting, and for the faster calculation. 
Is it right?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is partially correct. Regularization will not help with underfitting. It can protect (to some extent) from overfitting. Furthermore it will not speed up calculations (as it is actually more complex to compute something with added regularization) but can lead to simplier optimization problem - thus less number of steps required for convergenc (as a resulting error surface is more smooth).